# Onclick the expanded div acts weird

Tags: jquery, css

I want to do a portfolio page like [this one](http://creamyorange.com/).
I am using the masonry Jquery plugin.
So, when I click on a box, it should expand and push the other boxes, not lie underneath them.
So basically, on click I add a new width and height to the box that I am clicking, and display another `div` in the box.

If I add the `height` and `width` inline, the `div` pushes the other boxes like it should, but when I use jQuery, it just expands underneath them. [Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WA347/43/)

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="1" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('hover');" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('hover');">
        <div class="close-btn" id="cb_1"></div>
        <div class="box-content" id="bc_1">
            <img src="image.png" />
            <span class="title">Titlul clipului aici 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="big-box-content" id="bbc_1">
            <h1 class="title">Titlul clipului aici 1</h1>

            <img src="image.png" />
            <p>Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="2" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('hover');" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('hover');">
        <div class="close-btn" id="cb_2"></div>
        <div class="box-content" id="bc_2">
            <img src="image.png" />
            <span class="title">Titlul clipului aici 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="big-box-content" id="bbc_2">
            <h1 class="title">Titlul clipului aici 2</h1>

            <img src="image.png" />
            <p>Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese. Descrierea clipului aici in cateva randuri bune sa vedem cum iese.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
     .....
     .....
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    id = this.id;
    //if there is any box opened, close it
    $('.close-btn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.box-content').css('display', 'block');
    $('.big-box-content').css('display', 'none');
    $('.box').css('width', '200px').css('height', 'auto').css('padding', '10px');
    // open the clicked one
    $('#' + id).css('width', '650px').css('height', 'auto').css('padding', '15px');
    $('#bc_' + id).css('display', 'none');
    $('#bbc_' + id).css('display', 'block');
    $('#cb_' + id).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: you need to use the reload function of masonry, so that it will knows the new sizes.

Comment: that seems logic. i'll try to do that, if i find how to :)

Comment: thanks man! i re-run the masonry script after modifying the dimensions and it works! if you post an answer i'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: You should set css styles like this `$('.box').css({'width' : '200px', 'height' : 'auto', 'padding' : '10px'});`

Comment: @StevenFarley Thank you! I am very new to jQuery and any tip is appreciated. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the reload function of masonry.

```
    $(function(){

    $('.container').masonry('reload');

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WA347/45/

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with masonry, but it seems it adds `position:absolute;` to the elements. I suggest you try to use `position:relative;` instead.

Ie, change this line:

```
$('.container').masonry({ columnWidth:230 });
```

to this line:

```
$('.container').masonry({ columnWidth:230, position:relative });
```

Check out this section of their docs: [masonry: containerStyle](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#containerstyle)

Comment: With this line the masonry plugin doesn't work, but the box pushes the other boxes on expand (like expected)